# perform Fisher test comparing multiple dataframe columns to the same vector R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, chi-squared

I have a dataframe:

```
frequencies <- data.frame(row.names = c("a", "b", "c")
                          ,response = c(10, 7, 4)
                          ,no_response = c(12, 12, 7))

> frequencies
  response no_response
a       10          12
b        7          12
c        4           7
```

I would like to perform Fisher's exact test, comparing each row to the sum of observations from this experiment (i.e. to the frequencies observed for the whole experiment - I want to know whether frequencies observed in any of the  a/b/c data subsets are different from those observed for the whole dataset).

To do it "manually", I count how many observations I have in each column:

```
total <- colSums(frequencies) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  `rownames<-`("total")

> total
      response no_response
total       21          31
```

I then run `fisher.test()` (from which I only need the p value), comparing each column to `total[1,]`

```
ap <- fisher.test(rbind(total[1,], frequencies[1,]))$p.value
bp <- fisher.test(rbind(total[1,], frequencies[2,]))$p.value
```

and so on.

There must be a neater way. In the final output, I would like to have a column in the `frequencies` dataframe that contains the p values, looking like this:

```
  response no_response  pval
a       10          12   0.8
b        7          12     1
c        4           7     1
```

I added a `purrr` tag, because I feel I should be using `map` here but I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something simple like this with dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

total <- frequencies %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum))

frequencies %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(pval = stats::fisher.test(rbind(total, c(response, no_response)))$p.value) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### base:

##### using a for loop ::

```
frequencies$p.value<-0
for(i in 1:nrow(frequencies)){
  frequencies$p.value[i]<- fisher.test(rbind(total[1,], frequencies[i,1:2]))$p.value
}
```

###### or using apply::

```
rbindtest <- function(x) {
  fisher.test(rbind(total[1,], x))$p.value
}
frequencies$p.value<-apply(frequencies, 1, rbindtest)
```